# Get product custom field values as variables in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

I am using Woocommerce for registration for classes; each class/product has up to 20 custom fields, which I need to return as variables in order to highly customize the checkout and order details pages and customer email template.

I **don't** just want to add all of the custom meta data with hooks, because I need very tight control over the output. For instance, the following answer worked fine for including custom fields in the cart page:  [Display Custom Field's Value in Woocommerce Cart & Checkout items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893196/display-custom-fields-value-in-woocommerce-cart-checkout-items/43898948#43898948)

But I would like them in checkout, order details and emails as well, with full control over the HTML where they appear *(in some cases they will need to be converted as well, e.g., Unix timestamps to human readable time)*.

In `order-item-details.php` template I have tried the following:

```
$room = get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'room', true );
$room_number = get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'room_number', true );
$instructor = get_post_meta( $product->ID, 'instructor', true );

echo 'Your instructor is ' . $instructor . '.';
echo 'Your class is in ' . $room . '.';
```

But it didn't work…

How can I access and use custom field values associated with a specific product?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First **`$product->ID`** will not work any way. **So your problem is how to get the product ID.**

**Multiple cases**

1) In Archive pages like shop or in Single product pages:

- Using `get_the_id()` will give you mostly always the product id (the post ID)

  ```
  $room = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'room', true );
  ```
- You can also use `global $product;` with `$product->get_id()` if `$product` is not defined.

  ```
  global $product;

  $room = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'room', true );
  ```
- You can also use `global $post;` with `$post->ID` (if `$post` is not defined):

  ```
  global $post;

  $room = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'room', true );
  ```

---

2) for cart items (from the cart object):

```
// Loop through cart items
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    // Get the WC_Product object (instance)
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    $product_id = $product->get_id(); // get the product ID

    $room = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), 'room', true );
    ## … / … 
}
```

- Now for **product variations**, if you need to get **the parent variable product ID**, you will use:

  ```
  // Get the parent product ID (the parent variable product)
  $parent_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

  $room = get_post_meta( $parent_id, 'room', true );
  ## … / …
  ```

---

3) For order items *(from a defined `WC_Order` object `$order`)*:

```
// Loop through cart items
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
    // Get the Product ID
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

    $room = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'room', true );
    ## … / … 
}
```

- Now for **product variations**, if you need to get **the parent variable product ID**, you will use:

  ```
  // Loop through cart items
  foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
      // Get the parent Product ID
      $product = $item->get_product();
      $parent_id = $product->get_parent_id(); // The parent product ID

      $room = get_post_meta( $parent_id, 'room', true );
      ## … / … 
  }
  ```

So it's up to you now.