# woocommerce_before_calculate_totals doesn't work on custom single product template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

After 2-3 days of frustration and troubleshooting, I found the guilty: my custom single product templates. I found If I removed those custom templates with custom div and HTML arrangements - the design was broken, but the desired output was coming.

**My  main issue:** 
Based on *"[Product custom checkbox option that changes Woocommerce cart item price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58312696/product-custom-checkbox-option-that-changes-woocommerce-cart-item-price/58313221#58313221)"* annswer to my previous question, where an extra option (checkbox) can be **added to item price**, but it's is not adding to the total on cart page.

Is `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook doesn't work with custom `single-product.php`?

What is causing this?
what can be the fix?

Custom `Single-product.php` resting in `mytheme/woocommerce/single-product.php` here below:

```
<?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>

<div class="wrap wrap2">

    <div class="fcontent whitebg wshadow">
        <div class="frow">
            <h1 class="italic"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <img src="https://wptravelengine.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/2018/07/Stripe-Payment-1000x683.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
    </div><!-- content -->

    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="sleft whitebg">
            <?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; endif;?>
        </div>
        <div class="sright">
            <div class="somethemname_addcart browser-compatible whitebg">
                <form action="" id="order">
                    <div class="bbuynow">
                        <div class="bbuynow_one">
                            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php
                            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
                            ?>
                            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>          
                        </div>                          
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="browser-compatible whitebg">
                <h6>Browser compatibility</h6>
                <div class="browsers">
                    <div><img width="50px" height="50px" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/img/svg/browsers/chrome.svg" /></div>
                    <div><img width="50px" height="50px" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/img/svg/browsers/edge.svg" /></div>
                    <div><img width="50px" height="50px" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/img/svg/browsers/firefox.svg" /></div>
                    <div><img width="50px" height="50px" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/img/svg/browsers/opera.svg" /></div>
                    <div><img width="50px" height="50px" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/img/svg/browsers/safari.svg" /></div>
                    <div><img width="50px" height="50px" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/img/svg/browsers/internet-explorer.svg" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="browser-compatible whitebg">
                <table class="prod-desc">
                    <caption></caption>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Updated</td>
                        <td>January 29 2019</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Created</td>
                        <td>29 January 1206 B.C.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Compatible with</td>
                        <td>Woocommerce 3.X</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Four</td>
                        <td>4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Five</td>
                        <td>5</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Six</td>
                        <td>6</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Seven</td>
                        <td>7</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- fcontent whitebg -->

    <!-- This was the area for the table-->

</div>



<?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
    // do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

Similarly, `content-single-product.php` also is resting here →
`mytheme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php`