# Show a Specific Woocommerce Product Info Inside another Product Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Possible duplicate, but I couldn't get anything to work by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725057/get-product-custom-field-values-as-variables-in-woocommerce), so please bear with me.

Hi, I'm using Woocommerce with Advanced Custom Fields, and the goal is the following:

Product A: Field 1, 2, 3.

Product B: Field 1, 2, 3.

I wrote custom code in the product page template to retrieve all custom fields for products and show them on their respective product page, as follows:

```
$ACF_field_group_ID = 48; // ACF Field Group's Post ID
$fields = acf_get_fields($ACF_field_group_ID);
?> <ul> <?php
// if it has data, then...
   if (have_rows($field['name'])) {
//echo the field's human readable format.
   echo "Title: " . $field['label'];
// loop through all the uploaded files then echo their url and icon
   while (have_rows($field['name'])) {
   the_row();
$file = get_sub_field($field['name'] . '_group');
            ?>
<?php

   echo "<li><a href=" . $file['url'] . " target='_blank'>" . $file['title'] . " <img src= " . $file['icon'] . " width='10' height='10'><a/></li> ";
                    ?>
<?php } /* /while */
} ?> </ul> <?php
            
}
```

but I am now trying to show Product A's Field 1 inside Product B's product page. As you can see from the above code I didn't need the product's ID in order to show the correct info, how can I have that code run on specific products to get their info so I can show that info anywhere, including on other product pages? so for example

```
$wanted_product = get_post_meta(87); //specific product ID
```

then have the code to get the needed fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you should query posts with ACF, Docs: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

Fast example:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'p'         => 42, // ID of a page, post, or custom type
'post_type' => 'any'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
<ul>
<?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php the_field('event_thumbnail'); ?>" />
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to the right direction :)
I got it to work, I'll test the code for a bit to make sure there are no bugs, then post a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since Advanced Custom Fields provides helper functions using the WordPress query is not needed here. Only ACF's `get_field()` function is needed. Full code as below:

```
//https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/
            $shared_folder = get_field($acf_field_label, $product_id);
    
            foreach ( $shared_folder as $field_Shared ) {
            echo "<ul>" ;
// if it has data, then...
//Note: added _subfield, because that's how I setup my ACF repeater's subfield's name
            if ($field_Shared[$acf_field_label.'_subfield']['name']) {
                
            echo "<li> <img class='product-file-icon' src= " . $field_Shared[$acf_field_label.'_subfield']['icon'] . " > ". "<a href=" . $field_Shared[$acf_field_label.'_subfield']['url'] . " target='_blank'>" . $field_Shared[$acf_field_label.'_subfield']['title'] . "<a/>
        </li>"  ;
            }
  echo "</ul>" ;    
} //foreach
```