# Display custom data in cart and checkout page of woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to display some custom data before my product name in cart page and checkout page. Means my cart will be like this

1. customfield + originalproductname       $150                $150

I have seen some links like 
[Display Custom Field's Value in Woocommerce Cart & Checkout items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893196/display-custom-fields-value-in-woocommerce-cart-checkout-items) But in the solution I have also seen some $cart_data and $cart item. Is it the cart data received from $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

Anyone please help. Am new to word-press and filters

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: Override the template files**
You can do some [Template Overriding](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/), Copy `cart.php` from templates `cart` folder and `review-order.php` from `checkout` folder and put them in your theme's directory with the same directory structure as you copied them and do the changes you wish to the copied files.

**Option 2: Use filters:**

You can use filters, i found the `woocommerce_cart_item_name` which changes the title in cart and checkout page as you want

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', function($title, $cart_item){
  $my_field = get_post_meta($cart_item['product_id'], 'my_custom_field_key', true);


  return sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s - %s</a>', esc_url( get_permalink($cart_item['product_id']) ), $my_field, get_the_title($cart_item['product_id']) );
}, 10, 2);
```

you can look for more filters and actions by reading the template files in woocommerce plugin's templates directory